# No module named astropy

Tags: python, astropy

I've install the module Astropy for Python in mac using:

```
pip install --user astropy
```

It works when I installed but when I execute this code I have an error.

```
import astropy
astropy.test()
```

This is the error

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Users/JanPolRoig/Documents/astropytest.py", line 1, in <module>
  import astropy
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'astropy'
```

Why is this happening?

Comment: If you can't import the module why do you claim that it works? :puzzled:

Comment: It works when I installed

Comment: Isn't that an IDLE error message? It seems that IDLE does not know that the module was installed.

Comment: Can you pip install any other packages or is the problem somehow just with Astropy?

Comment: In your Python run `import sys; print(sys.path)`. I don't think the paths installed to by `--user` are necessarily on your Python path by default.

Comment: what is your Python setup? Which executable (full path) are you running for Python? How do you run your `astropytest.py` script?

Answer (score 1):

With the Python executable you're using, try installing it as follows:

```
python -m pip install --user astropy
```

It is likely the `pip` you're using does not match the `python` you're using.

Comment: Can you pip install other packages?

Comment: Can you pip install other packages?

Comment: Yes I can, the problem is with Astropy

Answer (score 0):

Check your `PYTHONPATH` environment variable. After pip installation with `--user` option, astropy could be stored in a directory like `~/.local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/`.

In bash you can do

`export PYTHONPATH=$HOME/.local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/`

You can include this line in the ~/.bashrc file.

Answer (score 0):

I faced this problem when I installed the updates for my "macOS Catalina". I'm using anaconda for python3. and I had to re-install it again. The problem is that some of the installation packages like ".matplotlip" or ".astropy" remain in the home directory (hidden) and when you load them instead of your anaconda path it goes to the location of these temporary files. I solved it by simply deleting them using

> rm -r .matplotlib

and similar packages in my home directory. I was using astropy for the "LightKurv" package.