# Astropy Permission Denied error

Tags: python, astropy

I'm currently a beginner to astropy, and as a part of a project I have to import some fits files or analysis. However, when I run the code to import astropy.io, I get a permission error.

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "gal.py", line 2, in <module>
    from astropy.io import fits
  File "/home/alex/anaconda3/lib/python3.6/site-packages/astropy/__init__.py", line 290, in <module>
_initialize_astropy()
  File "/home/alex/anaconda3/lib/python3.6/site-packages/astropy/__init__.py", line 213, in _initialize_astropy
    config.configuration.update_default_config(__package__, config_dir)
  File "/home/alex/anaconda3/lib/python3.6/site-packages/astropy/config/configuration.py", line 700, in update_default_config
    with open(template_path, 'wt', encoding='latin-1') as fw:
PermissionError: [Errno 13] Permission denied: '/home/alex/.astropy/config/astropy.3.0.2.cfg'
```

Can someone help me figure out how to fix this error?

Comment: I might suggest opening a bug report at github.com/astropy/astropy   while I agree with Matt Messersmith's answer that your probably do have an honest permission misconfiguration of your home directory (it might be helpful to know what platform you're on), Astropy should not fail to import just because it can't write the default config file. At the absolute worst this should just give a warning.

Answer (score 1):

I could not reproduce the error, so I'll admit some of this is guesswork. I suspect `chmod -R 755 /home/alex/.astropy` will resolve the issue.

If `/home/alex/.astropy` doesn't exist, create it first: `mkdir /home/alex/.astropy`.

After you execute these commands in your shell, try the import again.

Comment: Hi Matt thanks for the reply. Unfortunately that did not work, but I have found a solution: by running 'sudo python' instead of 'python'. It is definitely a permission error somewhere in the files Im unaware of, but for now sudo will have to do

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar issue on Windows 10. I tried uninstalling astropy but noticed that the old .cfg file in the .astropy folder was not removed by pip uninstall. So I deleted it manually and did a fresh pip install astropy. Problem solved!

Answer (score 0):

I had the same error and for me, it was happening for the same reason I explained here [1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50554094/no-module-named-astropy/61640265#61640265)
. You simply need to remove the hidden packages in your home directory (NOT the directory that your python/Anaconda is installed).